# Do files in /dev/shm take up memory when grown with ftruncate but are not written?

Tags: c, linux, posix, shared-memory

I'm using mmap to create shared memory segments, and I'm wondering if I can pre-create all the segments I'm going to possibly use in /dev/shm without triggering any memory use. The reason I suspect this may be possible is that I know most filesystems have a concept of all-zero pages, and it's possible when you initially grow a file before you do any writes to have the file not really take up space because of these 'hole' pages. But is this true for tmpfs (filesystem for /dev/shm)? Can I go wild making large  files in /dev/shm without triggering memory use as long as I don't write to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, the `tmpfs` file system supports sparse files. Just resizing the file does not allocate memory (beyond the internal `tmpfs` data structures). Just like with regular file systems which support sparse files (files with holes), you either have to actually write data or use `fallocate` to allocate backing storage.  As far as I can see, this has been this way since the Linux 2.6 days.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Do you know if this stay true even if you mmap the file? What if you mmap it and lock the pages? I imagine locking must force it...?